# Keras loss is always 0.0000e+00

Tags: tensorflow, keras, loss

I implemented an MLP with a custom loss function, here is the code:

```
def custom_loss(groups_id_count):
  print('Computing loss...')
  def listnet_loss(real_labels, predicted_labels):
    start_range = 0
    for group in groups_id_count:
      end_range = start_range + group[1]
      batch_real_labels = real_labels[start_range:end_range]
      batch_predicted_labels = predicted_labels[start_range:end_range]
      loss = -K.sum(get_top_one_probability(batch_real_labels)) * tf.math.log(get_top_one_probability(batch_predicted_labels))
      start_range = end_range
    print('loss: ', loss)
    return loss
  return listnet_loss
```

The loss printed epoch by epoch is always `0.0000e+00` and the `print` statement about `loss` variable is `Tensor("listnet_loss/mul_24:0", shape=(None, None), dtype=float32)`.

This is the `get_top_one_probability` function:

```
def get_top_one_probability(vector):
  return (K.exp(vector) / K.sum(K.exp(vector)))
```

**UPDATE**:

Output for `get_top_one_probability(batch_predicted_labels)` is always:

```
Tensor("listnet_loss/truediv_36:0", shape=(None, 1), dtype=float32)
```

The output of `real_labels` is:

```
Tensor("ExpandDims:0", shape=(None, 1), dtype=float32)
```

The output of `batch_real_labels` and `batch_predicted_labels` is always:

```
Tensor("listnet_loss/strided_slice:0", shape=(None, 1), dtype=float32)
```

**UPDATE 2**:

Using `K.shape(real_labels)` I notice that the shape is `(2,)`, but I expect that shape corresponds to the number of labels passed to the `fit` function. Is it wrong?

Is there something wrong with my loss function? Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you run your code, print `get_top_one_probability(batch_predicted_labels)`  and give us the output ? :)

Comment: @dallonsi Of course, question updated!

Comment: Are you using Tensorflow 1 or 2?

Comment: maybe also the values in the tensors ?

Comment: Are the groups intended to separate "samples" or to separate "classes"?

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal Tensorflow 2.
@dallonsi do you mean use `print_tensor` ?
@DanielMöller groups are samples, and I have to compute a loss value for each group and then aggregate those values into single one

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the scope of the variable `loss`. You also don't add losses each iteration of the loop.

Try the code below:

```
def listnet_loss(real_labels, predicted_labels):
    start_range = 0
    loss = 0
    for group in groups_id_count:
      end_range = start_range + group[1]
      batch_real_labels = real_labels[start_range:end_range]
      batch_predicted_labels = predicted_labels[start_range:end_range]
      loss += -K.sum(get_top_one_probability(batch_real_labels)) * tf.math.log(get_top_one_probability(batch_predicted_labels))
      start_range = end_range
    print('loss: ', loss)
    return loss
```

Comment: I got this error trying your code: `InvalidArgumentError:  Incompatible shapes: [6,1] vs. [4,1]
  [[node listnet_loss/add_1 (defined at <ipython-input-4-fa5bd90f5d1f>:28) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_3880]`
Maybe the sum between two groups with different shapes causes the problem? Each group has its own length

Comment: In that case, use `tf.reduce_mean` around `-K.sum()`: `loss += tf.reduce_mean(-K.sum(...))`.

Comment: ok, something changed. Now the loss is `Tensor("listnet_loss/add_24:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)` and value printed epoch by epoch is `nan`. I'm sure that groups are correct...is it right the way I pick my batches in the loop? I don't know very well how to treat tensors.

Comment: Are you using `model.fit()` or `GradientTape`? If `model.fit()`, is `groups_id_count` a tensor?

Comment: I'm using `model.fit()` and no, it's not a tensor. It 's a python list of tuple.

Comment: `groups_id_count` contains only references that tells me how to split the labels, nothing more.

Comment: I think that's the issue. `groups_id_count` is still a part of the computation graph, since it is used in loss computation. Try providing it as an input to the network and get it as an output without passing it through any layers. Then use it in computation of the loss.

Comment: Ok I'll try. However, using `tf.print()` I notice that loss has a value in some cycles, but then it turns to `nan`. I think that this behaviour happens because, at a certain point, `batch_real_labels` and `batch_predicted_labels` are empty.

Comment: If I provide `groups_id_count` as a tensor through input layer, it will still iterable?

Comment: Ok, I think that I figured out the issue. I didn't define the `batch_size` parameter of `fit` and `groups_id_count` involves all dataset entries. So I put `batch_size` equals to the dataset length because I want to pass the whole dataset to the network.